# Why is the loop printing wrong value?

Tags: php

The parameter for index 5 needs to be 0 in below code.

But The value for `echo($a[5])` comes `1.2325951644078E-32`.

The loop prints correct values for all other parameters except for 5th index (which needs to be 0 according to me).

Can anybody tell me why is that happening??

```
for($x=-2;$x<2.1;$x+=0.4){

     $a[] = $x*$x;
 }

echo($a[5]); //this is not printing 0 why?
```

Output is:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 2.56
    [2] => 1.44
    [3] => 0.64
    [4] => 0.16
    [5] => 1.2325951644078E-32
    [6] => 0.16
    [7] => 0.64
    [8] => 1.44
    [9] => 2.56
    [10] => 4
)
```

Comment: I'm asking about index 5

Comment: Be careful with floating point math, see this: https://3v4l.org/64b4f You can see it show the same result, it is because the way floating point is stored in the memory. Check this: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: So what can be done to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

it should be zero..
Modify your code like this and try..

```
 $a[] = number_format($x*$x,2);
```

Comment: Doing this  converts it into string.

Comment: @dev740  You can typecast it...(float)number_format($x*$x,2);

Answer (score 1):

Bro you forget to convert to number format before math.

```
for($x=-2;$x<2.1;$x+=0.4){

     $a[] = number_format($x)*number_format($x);
 }

echo($a[5]); // 0
```

Hope help this.

Comment: I got it by changing number_format($x)*number_format($x); to number_format($x,2)*number_format($x,2);